# Looking for audio player which not scanning audio files

Tags: audio-player

My question is in the title.

I try to find an audio player which does not scanning my music library, but which allows me to select some tracks in a folder (in a embedded browser) in order to read it. If it could also save the paths of my different music folders, it would be perfect. In brief, I'm looking for an old-fashion audio player.

I've tested a lot of ones, but without success. Until now, under 14.04, I used Decibel-audio-player. It was definitely the lighter and the more useful audio player I have ever used. But, well, it is not maintained anymore. Yes, it is quite sad. :-(

So, which other audio player can suit me ? Any ideas are welcome. It could be, if nothing else exists, a "lot of features" audio player with a dedicated plugin.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't setup a "library", most players including the default Rhythmbox will NOT scan anywhere. And you can even use the Videos (Totem) to play music as well as VLC, neither scan.

Comment: Thank for for your response. Yes, I can use Video or VLC, it is currently my workaround. If I have no other alternative, yes again, I will try with Rhythmbox... but I would be happy to find a lighter audio player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clementine might work. You don't need to add folders to the library, you can just play from the file browser:

[image]

You can add to the libarary for scanning, if you wish, but it's not necessary. It's in the repositories, so a simple `sudo apt install clementine` is enough.

Comment: Thank your for your response. Clementine does the job, you're right. But it doesn't bookmark the favorite folders. Because I have different music folders on different hard drives, I need to browser in all the folder tree to switch between my different sources. Not as confortable as Decibel-Audio-Player was.

Comment: A simple solution is to create a bunch of links to those folders in a single folder and browse that folder. I guess that's the point where most devs move to libraries.

Comment: Well, it sounds as a good option. I had not thought about that. If there is no alternative...

Answer (score 0):

[Quodlibet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can do this too (source / disclaimer: I'm one of the developers).

Whilst it generally *does* work best with a library / metadata approach, this need not be set, scanning is optional, and there is a [File System Browser](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/browse/filesystem.html) built in...

As for bookmarking of favourites, not currently (other than the standard GTK bookmarks) but that's been mentioned the [Github issues list](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet/issues) - please add one if you feel strongly.

Comment: Oh ! It's even better ! With Quodlibet it's possible to hide all the features I don't need. I missed the File System Browser when I've tested it few weeks ago. Very very good. Thanks a lot (and also for the Github link). :-)